Probability of events containing quantifiers
At Brzezniak, Zastawniak, Basic Stochastic Processes, pp. 192-193 we find that $ξ(t),ζ(t), t\in T\subseteq \Bbb R$ are modifications of one another, if
$$P\{ξ(t)=ζ(t)\}=1, \rm for~all~t\in T ~(1).$$
We find also that, if $T\subseteq \Bbb R$ is a countable set, then $(1)$ is equivalent to the condition
$$P\{ξ(t)=ζ(t), \rm for~all~t\in T\}=1~(2).$$
The question is:
a. What is the precise and formal presentation of formula $(2)$ in terms of $P(A)$, where $A\in \mathcal F$?
b. What is the precise difference between formulae $(1),(2)$?

The probability that for some "point" t greater-or-equal to zero (maybe time?) The event  X(t) belongs to set A.

@MauroALLEGRANZA you just read the logical sentence inside the argument of the example! : )

Maybe we need the original reference to the formula... if we remove the quantiifer, the part ${ t \in [0, \infty) \mid X(t) \in A }$ looks like an event.

@MauroALLEGRANZA it looks like the sentence inside the argument that I denote in the question is related to the set that you quote in some way like "${t\in[0,\infty)|X(t)\in A}\neq \emptyset$". So the probability would be $P({t\in[0,\infty)|X(t)\in A}\neq \emptyset)$ -however we are still acting intuitively.

I think that sentence actually corresponds to/means the set ${ X(t) \in A :|: t \in [0,\infty) }$.

@JulioDiEgidio suppose for convenience that your set is a singleton, which means that  ${X(t)\in A|t\geq 0}={X(t_0)}$ for a $t_0\geq 0$. Then what is the meaning of $P({X(t_0)})$? Weird it seems. We have also to consider that every argument of $P$ must be an event, namely an element of σ-algebra on $Ω$. I cannot see how your set is an event.

Context that you've added in the comments to my answer below and should be added to the question: $\Omega = [0, \infty)$, $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ are fixed. Then $\exists t \in \Omega : X(t) \in A$ is either true or false, it does not makes sense to evaluate $P$ on it.

@ronno My question is exactly about that. All you write is a repetition of my question 's elements. I am stating that this kind of entities cannot be events (because they are sentences not elements of a σ-algebra) BUT in bibliography we read these forms very usually.

Please include an example source of where you've seen this sort of an expression. I suspect there is some misunderstanding in what the actual sample space $\Omega$ is supposed to be.

E.g.
$P(X\in D ~\forall t)$ (Rao, Introduction to Stochastic Calculus, p. 37)
$P(X_t=X'_t ~\rm {for~all~t})$(Fritz, Victor, Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths: Theory and Applications, p.571)

$P(\frac {|W(t)|}{t}>CM~\rm{for~some~t}\in [0,\frac{1}{}c^2])$ (Brzezniak,Zastawniak,Basic Stochastic Processes, p.159). I hope you are convinced.

In all of those examples, $\Omega \ne [0, \infty)$ necessarily, but $X$ is a function on $\Omega \times [0, \infty)$, written $X_t$ or $X(t) = X(\omega, t)$ for fixed $\omega \in \Omega$. In Karandikar-Rao, see the explanation immediately after that definition. In Fritz-Victor, see the definition on that same page 571. In Brzezniak-Zastawniak, see the definition of a stochastic process on page 139. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Does anything of all these answer my question?: How/What does it mean when we write a sentence and not an event as an argument of a probability function?

The point is that it's not a sentence in the sense of propositional logic, there's a free variable $\omega$ hidden in the notation.

I just noticed that you edited your answer and wrote "$ω\in Ω$" instead the previous "$X\in Ω$". I think that it begins to make sense!

Yes, I'm more used to the convention where you think of the elements of $\Omega$ directly as the functions of $t$ instead of parametrizing a fixed random variable (including coincidentally in a course I was taught by Rao). Also FYI I don't get notified of your comments unless you include @ronno (or the comment is on one of my posts).

If $\phi(x)$ is a formula with one free variable $x$ then $P(\phi(x))$ is usually understood to be $P(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \phi(\omega)\})$. The formula $\phi(x)$ can involve whatever other variables and quantifiers, as long as it makes the set $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \phi(\omega)\}$ lie in the relevant $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. In your example there is an implicit variable $\omega \in \Omega$ and $X(t)$ is really shorthand for $X(\omega, t)$ with $\omega$ fixed. So
$$P(~\exists t\in [0,\infty): X(t)\in A) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid ~\exists t\in [0,\infty): X(\omega, t) \in A\}) .$$

The second line says $P{ω|in Ω|φ(ω)}$, which makes sense, because the probability 's argument lies in sample space $Ω$. Though the last equality (the right hand) gives as argument a set containing values of r.v. in sample space; the r.v. is defined at $Ω$ and maps into $\Bbb R$. We would expect the set contaning sample points not $X$ 's values.

*I mean $P{ω\in Ω|φ(ω)}$. Sorry.

What do you mean by "the r.v. is defined at $\Omega$ and maps into $\mathbb{R}$"?

I mean $X:Ω\to \Bbb R$.

If $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and you're evaluating $X$ at $t \in [0, \infty)$, is $\Omega$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Is $A$ fixed? Then $\Omega$ is not the right sample space for that probability.

As you can see, here $Ω=[0,\infty)$ and $A$ is a Borel set on $\Bbb R$. So "$X\in Ω$" makes no sense, for $X$ takes its values from real line. The Borel set $A$ is fixed for our conversation: for $X$ a real r.v. on $Ω=[0,\infty)$ and $A\in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ in which way ${\exists t \in[0,\infty):X(t)\in A}$ can denote an event?
